# How do I implement a cycle-through array with a generator function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator, yield

Today I was wondering what would be the swiftest method to provide a cycle-through array in TypeScript, as in:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

where the next value after `three` would be `one`, and I thought that it's a good candidate for a generator function. However it does not seem to work for me. What's wrong with the following code?

```
function* stepGen(){
  const steps = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  let index = 0;

  if(index < steps.length - 1){
   index++;
  } else {
   index = 0;
  }
  yield steps[index];
}

let gen = stepGen();
console.log(gen.next().value); 
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value); // should be 'three'
console.log(gen.next().value); // should be 'one'
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Comment: You need to have a loop in your generator code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a loop in your generator code, otherwise there is only one `yield` happening:

```js
function* stepGen(steps){
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield steps[index];
    index = (index+1)%steps.length;
  }
}

let gen = stepGen(['one', 'two', 'three']); // pass array to make it more reusable
console.log(gen.next().value); 
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Alternatively you can also use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) which yields values from an iterable, one by one:

```js
function* stepGen(steps){
  while (true) yield* steps;
}

let gen = stepGen(['one', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(gen.next().value); 
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
console.log(gen.next().value);
```

Comment: Also if you take the array as an argument, it's an immediately usable block for OP

Comment: @BalázsÉdes, thanks, I incorporated that improvement idea.

Comment: True, @BalázsÉdes is right - I too am discovering the power of new stuff, like Map, Set or generators. Wasn't quite sure I'd ever need a generator, but with syntax possible as this one, it's just a dream. Wondering though, why jsfiddle.net spits out errors when trying to run this code under JavaScript 1.7 or TypeScript. Had to resort to regular JavaScript option in the fiddle.

Comment: Seems to work with [Javascript 1.7](https://jsfiddle.net/7zgrgbm7/), but the TypeScript version in jsfiddle does not support `yield`. I suppose it is not version 1.6.