# Return word from array in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm having the following script to get a word from the array (all, some or one) **randomly**, every 150ms. Now, I'd like to get the word from the array not randomly, but in a **loop** (so having in order 'all', 'some', 'one', 'all', 'some', 'one' and so on). How should I do it?

```js
var array = ['all', 'some', 'one'],
  words = null;
var getWord = function() {
  return [array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]];
};
setInterval(function() {
  words = getWord();
  $('#random-word').html(words[0]);
}, 150);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="random-word"></p>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to find a solution?

Comment: [How do I implement a cycle-through array with a generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404182)

Comment: As @fjc says, it would be useful if we knew how you were attempting to solve this problem in the first place. It's always a good idea to tackle the issue first before getting someone to provide the answer, as you'll better understand why the answer you get is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have a persistent counter variable that you increment on every call of `getWord`:

```js
const array = ['all', 'some', 'one']
let counter = 0;
const getWord = () => array[counter++ % array.length];

setInterval(() => {
  $('#random-word').html(getWord());
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-word"></div>
```

Or, if you don't like the `++` in an expression context:

```js
const array = ['all', 'some', 'one']
let counter = 0;
const getWord = () => {
  const word = array[counter % 3];
  counter++;
  return word;
};

setInterval(() => {
  $('#random-word').html(getWord());
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-word"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `counter` and reset it every time it gets bigger than the array length

```js
var array = ['all', 'some', 'one'];
words = null;
var i = 0;
var getWord = function() {

  if (i == array.length)
    i = 0;
  return [array[i++]];
};
setInterval(function() {
  words = getWord();
  console.log(words[0]);
}, 150);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to go is to create a custom iterator, that will return the next array index within the permitted range on every interation:

```js
var array = ['all', 'some', 'one'],
    words = null;

var iterator = (function* (min, max) {
    let pointer = min;
    while (true) {
        if (pointer > max) {
            pointer = 0
        }
        yield pointer;
        pointer++
    }
})(0, array.length - 1);

var getWord = function () {
    return [array[iterator.next().value]];
};
setInterval(function () {
    words = getWord();
    $('#random-word').html(words[0]);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random-word"></div>
```